# Why isn't the new Token 2022 metadata being picked up by explorers/Phantom?

Tags: metadata, token-2022

I've created a Token 2022 mint with the metadata extension, and I'm not sure if most apps support the new format.
Here's the token: https://explorer.solana.com/address/8NSuCtv9sC7e89P8yLPXinPtNvfC4CRHSunVsQUWfBVL?cluster=testnet

I created it with the new metadata extension, and I can only see the image/symbol when I look at my tokens in Phantom. I can't see the image/symbol when previewing how a transaction would change balances ("Unknown" is reported by Phantom) and solana explorer won't use the image/symbol.

Do I also need to create something like metaplex metadata or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the applications previously mentioned may not provide extensive support for Token 2022 at this time.
For a more comprehensive overview of token info and metadata, I recommend exploring https://solana.fm/. This platform may provide a more robust and detailed perspective on Token 2022.